# Using nlinfit to fit Gaussian to x,y paired data

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use Matlab's nlinfit function to estimate the best fitting Gaussian for x,y paired data. In this case, x is a range of 2D orientations and y is the probability of a "yes"  response.

I have copied @norm_funct from relevant posts and I'd like to return a smoothed, normal distribution that best approximates the observed data in y, and returns the magnitude, mean and SD of the best fitting pdf. At the moment, the fitted function appears to be incorrectly scaled and less than smooth - any help much appreciated!

```
x = -30:5:30;
y = [0,0.20,0.05,0.15,0.65,0.85,0.88,0.80,0.55,0.20,0.05,0,0;];

% plot raw data
figure(1)
plot(x, y, ':rs');
axis([-35 35 0 1]);

% initial paramter guesses (based on plot)
initGuess(1) = max(y);  % amplitude
initGuess(2) = 0;       % mean centred on 0 degrees
initGuess(3) = 10;      % SD in degrees

% equation for Gaussian distribution
norm_func = @(p,x) p(1) .* exp(-((x - p(2))/p(3)).^2);

% use nlinfit to fit Gaussian using Least Squares
[bestfit,resid]=nlinfit(y, x, norm_func, initGuess);

% plot function
xFine = linspace(-30,30,100);
figure(2)
plot(x, y, 'ro', x, norm_func(xFine, y), '-b');
```

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I missed the notification of your answer but thanks very much for the advice. Your explanation and example are very clear and useful!!

Comment: Great, glad to help! – Would you "accept" the answer then, click on the empty checkmark below the number on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data actually represent probability estimates which you expect come from normally distributed data, then fitting a curve is not the right way to estimate the parameters of that normal distribution. There are different methods of different sophistication; one of the simplest is the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)), which means you choose the parameters such that the moments of the theoretical distribution match those of your sample. In the case of the normal distribution, these moments are simply mean and variance (or standard deviation). Here's the code:

```
% normalize y to be a probability (sum = 1)
p = y / sum(y);

% compute weighted mean and standard deviation
m = sum(x .* p);
s = sqrt(sum((x - m) .^ 2 .* p));

% compute theoretical probabilities
xs = -30:0.5:30;
pth = normpdf(xs, m, s);

% plot data and theoretical distribution
plot(x, p, 'o', xs, pth * 5)
```

The result shows a decent fit:

[image]

You'll notice the factor 5 in the last line. This is due to the fact that you don't have probability (density) estimates for the full range of values, but from points at distances of 5. In my treatment I assumed that they correspond to something like an integral over the probability density, e.g. over an interval [x - 2.5, x + 2.5], which can be roughly approximated by multiplying the density in the middle by the width of the interval. I don't know if this interpretation is correct for your data.

Your data follow a Gaussian curve and you describe them as probabilities. Are these numbers (`y`) your raw data – or did you generate them from e.g. a histogram over a larger data set? If the latter, the estimate of the distribution parameters could be improved by using the original full data.